# Change login site URL of app, does it change page access tokens?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have persisted to database some very important page access tokens to our application. Now we need to change the login site url. Will this have any impact on our page access tokens, will they still be valid? I need to know because we do not wish to involve our very important clients with this, since we are actually using these tokens and it will be very difficult for us to involve the clients to get new tokens right now.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this have any impact on our page access tokens, will they still be valid?

**Yes**, the token will still be valid.

The page access token will be invalidated if the user de-authorized your app/ changes password; it has nothing to do with the site url.